# How to re-render the page while using router.push() in Next.JS 14 app directory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js14

When I navigate between pages using `router.push()` in the **app** directory (**Next.JS 14**), the page which is rendered is the **cached version** of that page (the page(s) to which I nagivate using `router.push()` is/are server component(s) and not client component(s)).

It does not **re-render** the page, i.e. instead of fetching the data again from the server and then rendering the page, it **renders the cached version** of that page.

My requirement is such that whenever I navigate using `router.push()`, **the page should be re-rendered without using any cached version of that page**.

I've tried various methods to address this, including setting `export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"` and `export const revalidate = 0`, but none of them have resolved the issue for me.

Could anyone offer insights or suggestions on how to ensure that pages re-render without using cached versions when navigating using `router.push()` in Next.js 14? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
router.push("/path");
router.refresh() // i think
```

Comment: It seems to work, but is there a way for it to be done automatically without writing `router.refresh()` everytime.

Comment: i don't know that... :(

Comment: I appreciate your response. It would be more convenient if the solution didn't require manual refreshing.